# On Raspberry Pi - Auto start terminal after login?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm working on a small project right now. I want the python script to automatically run after loggin into the GUI.

I followed the steps here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/view ... 91&t=65607

But it didn't work for me. What it did was whenever I open up the terminal, the script will run automatically, but not after loggin into the GUI.

So I figured a easy solution is to configure the system so terminal runs after loggin into GUI.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To auto-start the terminal on boot, open this file with nano:

```
nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Add this line to the end of the file:

```
@lxterminal
```

Close, save and reboot

Reference and some other goodies to run a script on startup as well which may have been what you are actually looking for:
http://blog.startingelectronics.com/auto-start-a-desktop-application-on-the-rapberry-pi/

Comment: Solved my problem! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Brilliant answer

Comment: If you want to start it with a command, add it to the line like `@lxterminal -e sudo python script.py`

Answer (score 17):

When you edit or create ***autostart*** file in your user space like

```
~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

then, this file will override global lxsession ***autostart*** file in

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

so you should copy everything from global file to your newly created file.
By this way , after reboot you won't get a blank screen running openbox.

So, your file should contain

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
point-rpi
```

And then add your necessary startup items at the bottom like

```
@lxterminal
```

Comment: This should be voted higher, I just spent hours trying to understand why I was booting into `Obconfig` without being able to properly exit it.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to launch a terminal and **automatically run a script inside it**, you can do so by passing the `--command` parameter to the `lxterminal` command.

#### Open the autostart file

```sh
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

#### Edit the autostart file

Right above the `@xscreensaver` line, add `@lxterminal --command=/path/to/script"`

My `autostart` file looks something like this.

```sh
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@lxterminal --command="/path/to/script"
@xscreensaver -no-splash
point-rpi
```

**Note:** In some places, it is suggested to use the `-e` flag instead of `--command` parameter in `lxterminal`, however that did not work for me. This did.

Comment: This wasn't working for me. You need to have `@lxterminal` at the end of the file, and use `-e`, no equal sign and no quotes, as in `@lxterminal -e sudo python3 script.py`

Answer (score 0):

In case you need the terminal running with your Python script do this:

#1 Edit file with vi or nano:

sudo vi /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

#2 Add this command at the end of the file:

@lxterminal -e python /home/here-is-your-python-script.py

#3 Save and exit and you can test it with:

sudo reboot