# Python script not able to find package when executed from terminal at bootup, what am I doing wrong? [Raspbian]

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, raspberry-pi, startup

sorry in case this is obvious or redundant, I've been looking around on this site for an answer to this problem but I couldn't find anything that would fix it

What I am trying to achieve is executing a Python script when my raspberry pi turns on (after the desktop loads in)

I've been trying to do so by adding these lines at the end of `/home/pi/.bashrc`

```
echo Running at boot

sudo /usr/bin/python3.7m  /home/pi/Desktop/Program/NameOfTheProgram.py
```

The problem, as you might've guessed from the title, is that when the script is executed as I open the terminal, and consequently at bootup, python doesn't appear to be capable of finding a package

```
    from SSIM_PIL import compare_ssim as ssim #Import ssim from ssim package
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SSIM_PIL'
```

This problem does not arise when I execute the script from the terminal by using

```
/usr/bin/python3.7m  /home/pi/Desktop/Program/NameOfTheProgram.py
```

in which case the program is executed as intended, so my only guess is that this shouldn't be a problem with the python version I'm using, since I'm 100% sure it's the same one and it apparently *should* work, but I may be mistaken

I've also tried to put those same lines of code in `/etc/rc.local`, but to no avail

Am I missing something? Thank you in advance

Comment: Does the error also occur when you run the script as `sudo`, like in your script example?

Comment: Have you checked the value of the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable? Alternatively you could launch the file with a virtual environment python interpreter, just to be completely sure that your dependencies are met exactly as required every time.

Comment: Hi! Running the script from the terminal with `sudo` did indeed stop it from working, hence by removing it from `.bashrc` it caused the program to work as intended! Thanks!

Comment: This is the first time i've ever heard of the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, so I defenetly haven't looked into it, so it could possibly be a cause of the problem

Comment: @DubiousShrub Normally, you don't need to set `PYTHONPATH`. Question: why were you running your code with `sudo` if it was obviously not required? That seems like an unnecessary security risk.

Comment: @RolandSmith I've never coded on raspberry pi (nor Python) before, so I have the tendency to add `sudo` to all of my shell scripts to avoid "permission denied" errors, although now I must admit that it clearly wasn't the best approach

Comment: @DubiousShrub In general UNIX systems like raspbian are set up to restrict *write* access in system directories. And that is a good thing because it is not that difficult to render a system *unusable* by accidentally overwriting critical files. So while using `sudo` is better than just giving a script `root` privileges, it should not be done thoughtlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is me again, like Roberto pointed out removing `sudo` from the command did indeed work to execute the program when a terminal window is opened

Unfortunately this didn't initiate the program at startup, but in theory all I need to do now is find a way to open a terminal window with a terminal command, and the program should be working correctly

This is admittedly a bit contrived, but it's good enough as long as the program works

To open the terminal on boot I've edited the `autostart` file in the `lxsession` folder by adding `@lxterminal` to it, as illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36466625/18241995)

I'm answering to my own question as I don't know how to mark a comment as "answer", if that's even possible

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run scripts at different moments:

1. At system boot (see [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/850333/213753), or use `cron`'s [`@reboot` feature](https://raspiserver.com/crontab-on-raspberry-pi/)).
2. When users log in to their shell.
3. When users open a new terminal.
4. On an arbitrary given time (using `cron` and `crontab`; read the manual pages!)

Concerning 2 and 3; this depends somewhat on the shell you use.
Read the manual of the user's shell and look in the FILES section.

If a script does not require root privileges, I'm a fan of using `cron`, because it supports running commands as a non-root user.